# How to get PHP CLI to find its DLL?

Tags: php, windows-xp

Running Windows PHP 4.4.2 \cli\php.exe fails with an error "Cannot find php4ts.dll" if the current directory is anything other than the one containing this DLL. How can I run the .exe from another current directory? I'd rather not amend the installation directory content.

Comment: PHP 4 in year 2012? CLI on Windows? I realy hope it is only for self educational pupose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy it to `c:\windows\system32`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather use installation directory as issued.  I am assuming the php.exe should be launchable from the installation directory as issued... just that I have not yet found out how :)

Comment: Well, if adding (for example) `c:\php\cli` to your PATH environmental variable doesn't do the trick I think you have to copy it there, sometimes it works if the PHP is compiled to look for the DLL in the same folder. You COULD also try registering the DLL with Windows, like: `c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe c:\php\cli\php4ts.dll` but otherwise most google results I've looked at too recommends a copy of that file to the windows folder. :/